# mysql query: to get number of devices according to its occurrence in given date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have following schema for my table:

```
id int(11)
dev_id varchar(50)
rec_date date
```

Suppose user enters a date range from 2014-08-01 to 2014-08-31.

Output should be like this:

- How many dev_id are present only once in any of the date and not in
  another,
- how many dev_id are common in two dates,
- how many dev_id are common in three dates and so on till
- how many dev_id are common in all 31 days.

I am confused about this. Can it be done at the database level or I have to manipulate it in server side scripting language.

Comment: It could be done in either MySQL or in PHP. How would you use the data? That should help you decide where to implement these queries.

Comment: I want to create a query for it as I am dealing with very large record set.

Comment: Yeah - define "query" - you presumably don't want to write all these queries out by hand, but what I mean is how will you be using the data that this outputs? There are many factors to consider when deciding how to implement efficient PHP/MySQL integration - speed, request numbers, query time, number of queries to perform, etc

Comment: I have to show data in tabular format. like this: no of occurrence -> total device. e.g 1 - 17 (means 17 devices were present only once in that date range).

Comment: If you set up an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some example data in your table I'll have a look - as it stands here it'll be tedious to replicate.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.